# How to read XML data in salesforce?

Tags: visualforce, xml, apex-webservice, xmlparsing

I get data in XML from a web service from a connector URL, the xml contains data about people, now I have to read the names, emailids from that xml and compare with my org's contacts and so some operations. So how do I read it?

Answer (score 1):

You need either `Dom` or `XmlStreamReader` class to parse your xml response. You can find sample code in the below links.

Xml parsing using XmlStreamReader:-
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_streaming_reading.htm

Xml parsing using Dom:-
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm

Comment: Please do not post link only answers as they can lose their value if the links break, include a bit of relevant information from the linked site.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing in the past.
I fixed it fist by parsing the XML retrieved from connect into JSON using `xml2js` library

```
const parser = new xml2js.Parser();
const message = await parser.parseStringPromise(xml);
```

The fields that you add to a DocuSign document are included deep into the json structure

```
const tabStatus = message.DocuSignEnvelopeInformation.EnvelopeStatus[0].RecipientStatuses[0].RecipientStatus[0].TabStatuses[0];
```

Then, you just need to find the element of the value that you want. In this example, I search for a field with tab label `amount`, and extract the value using `TabValue[0]`

```
const amount = tabStatus.TabStatus.find(field => field.TabLabel[0] == 'amount')
subscription.amount = amount.TabValue[0];
```

hope it helps.